# Android Service refresh location

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-location

I have a service that fetches data from an api. I want to implement a location manager so I could get user location and update the lat and lng.
I have this service that gets refreshed each minute, and loads data from an API by calling LoadPlaces(it creats an object). So I want to get the lat and lng of user and pass it to the object.
The code is as it follows. Any help?
Thanks

```
public class DownloadPlaceService extends Service {
Double lat, lng;

public DownloadPlaceService() {

}

private static final String TAG = "TAG";
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 400;
protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i("StartCommand", "started");
    lat = 42.01;
    lng = 21.22;

}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 0, 0, locationListener);


    final Context context = this;

    Log.w("Coordinates",lat+"");

    LoadPlaces reloadPersons = new LoadPlaces(
            this,
            new onDownloadPlaceDatabaseNotification(this),
            lat,
            lng
    );
    reloadPersons.execute();
    Log.i("StartCommand","reloaded persons");
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

}

Comment: where is your problem?

Comment: And your question is...?